# Normalizing product of ordered categorical CDFs

Tags: distributions, categorical-data, normalization

Let $\mathbf{p} = [p_1, \ldots, p_K]^\top$ and $\mathbf{q} = [q_1, \ldots, q_K]^\top$ define categorical distributions over a set of classes $\mathcal{C}_1, \ldots, \mathcal{C}_K$. Define $P_i = \sum_{i' \leq i} p_{i'}$ and $Q_i = \sum_{i' >= i} q_{i'}$. $\mathbf{P} = [P_1, \ldots, P_K]^\top$ and $\mathbf{Q} = [Q_1, \ldots, Q_K]^\top$ thus define the forward and reverse cumulative distribution functions for $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ when the classes are ordered by index $1 \leq i \leq K$. Is there a way to normalize $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{P} \odot \mathbf{Q}$, where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise (or Hadamard) product, to yield $\mathbf{\tilde{r}}$ such that:

1. $\tilde{r}_i = 0 \: \forall \: i$ if $\arg\min \{p_i : p_i > 0\} > \arg\min \{q_i : q_i > 0\}$
2. $\tilde{r}_i \propto r_i$, $0 \leq \tilde{r}_i \leq 1$, and $\sum_i \tilde{r}_i = 1$ (i.e., a valid probability distribution), otherwise

I have tried the following:

1. $\tilde{r}_i = \frac{r_i + \epsilon}{\sum_j (r_j + \epsilon)}$. This violates condition 1 above by setting all $\tilde{r}_i = 1/K$.
2. $\tilde{r}_i = \frac{r_i - a}{b - a}$ where $a = \min_i r_i$ and $b = \max_i r_i$. This violates condition 2 above by setting all $\tilde{r}_i = 0$ when both $p_1 = 1$ and $q_K = 1$. Moreover, the $\mathbf{\tilde{r}}$ obtained via this method is not a valid probability distribution.